# Incorrect results when using bash arithmetic operator in if condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

```
salary=(30000 45000 15000 40000)
average=37500
ans=0
for i in ${salary[@]}
do
  if [ $((i<average)) ]
  then
    ans=$((ans+1))
  fi
done
echo $ans
```

I am traversing through the salary array using for-loop, inside the for-loop, there is an if condition.

There are only two fields in array that suits `if [ $((i<average)) ]` condition, 30000 and 15000.

But it showing 4

Expected output is 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra `[..]` over the arithmetic evaluation is redundant. The presence of it "forces" a string evaluation of the result of the arithmetic evaluation. Either of "0" or "1" from the `$((..))` is evaluated as `[ -n 0 ]` and `[ -n 1 ]` which is always true.

So just use the arithmetic operator alone or use the arithmetic comparator inside `[..]`, i.e.

```
if (( i < average )); then
```

or

```
if [ "$i" -lt "$average" ]; then
```